# I have a problem to loadFromMemory from Map array

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a little problem to solve (sfml librairy).

```
void loadTexture::chargeTexture(string name){
    map<string, const unsigned char* > myMap = {
        { "balle", balle},
        { "truc", truc }
    };
    if(texture.loadFromMemory(myMap["balle"], sizeof(myMap["balle"]))){
        std::cout<< "image ok"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

This first code don't loadFromMemory but without compilation error (Failed to load image from memory. Reason: Corrupt PNG)

but this is ok.

```
void loadTexture::chargeTexture(string name){
    map<string, const unsigned char* > myMap = {
        { "balle", balle},
        { "truc", truc }
    };
    if(texture.loadFromMemory(balle, sizeof(balle))){
        std::cout<< "image ok"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I don't know why the loading works from the const, but none from the map. (for this demo I don't use the param (string name) of the function just to be clear for you.
texture is declared before as a Texture of course.

Comment: `sizeof(myMap["balle"])` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the data it points to.  Where does `balle` come from? It isn't shown in your example. Consider using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` as the map value then you can use the `size()` function to determine how much data it holds.

Comment: Tank you for your comment. balle is a binary embed with this declaration : 
static const unsigned char balle[] = {0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47,....}

Comment: You'r right, when I test with this : if(texture.loadFromMemory(myMap["balle"], 5873)) it's works.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every misuse of `sizeof` I've seen on this site...

Answer (score 1):

You do not show us the type declaration of `balle`. I guess it is an array. Therefore `sizeof(balle)` is the size of the whole array.
The `std::map` stores only the pointer to the first byte of `balle`:
`sizeof(myMap["balle"])` == `sizeof(const unsigned char*)`, which is the size of the pointer which is 8 bytes on 64 bit architecture.

*Solution:*: You have to store the first byte *and* the size of the image into your map. You may use `std::span`, or `std::string_view` for this.
Or just use a pair with pointer and size:

```cpp
void loadTexture::chargeTexture(string name){
    map<string, pair<const unsigned char*, size_t> > myMap = {
        { "balle", {balle, sizeof(balle)} },
        { "truc", {truc, sizeof(truc)} }
    };

    const pair<const unsigned char*, size_t> &img = myMap["balle"];
    if(texture.loadFromMemory(img.first, img.second)){
        std::cout<< "image ok"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you it's a good way. It's working.